# Is there a function in python equivalent to "bwconncomp" and "label matrix" from matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, 3d

I currently have a matlab script than I'm trying to write in python and I was wondering if there any equivalent functions to "bwconncomp" and "label matrix" in python that can assess multidimensional binary arrays.

Comment: The first step of [ask] is "Search, and research". What research have you done? What have you found? How have those options not met your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `skimage` library, you can do labeling connected components of a discrete image. Two pixels are connected when they are neighbors and have the same value. In 2D, they can be neighbors either in a 1- or 2-connected sense.

```
from skimage import measure
all_labels = measure.label(blobs)
```

You can find more details [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html) and [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html)